# Show that $B=\{f \in A^\Bbb R \mid f\mid_{f^{-1}(A \setminus \{0\})} \text{ injective } \} \subset A^\Bbb R$ is a compact set.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A=\overline{\{2^{-n} \mid n \in \Bbb N\}} \subset \Bbb R$. Show that $B=\{f \in A^\Bbb R \mid f\mid_{f^{-1}(A \setminus \{0\})} \text{ injective } \} \subset A^\Bbb R$ is a compact set.

First off $A$ is compact as it's closed (closure) and bounded by $1/2$. This implies that $A^\Bbb R$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem.

We only need to show that $B$ is closed as a closed subset of compact set is closed.

To show that $B$ is closed  I'm thinking of picking a net $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}$ such that $f_\alpha \to f \in A^\Bbb R$ and then trying to argue that $f$ must be in $B$. But I don't know how this is true.

It is not true that net of injective functions must converge to injective function so it's this restriction business to $f^{-1}(A \setminus \{0\})$ that's making the difference here.

I think that $A$ is actually the set $[0,1/2]$ and $A \setminus \{0\} = (0,1/2]$ so there is something about $0$ here that is breaking things. Can I have some hints on what to do with this?

Comment: $A=\{2^{-n} \mid n \in \Bbb N\}\cup\{0\}\ne[0,1/2].$

Comment: I see, thanks. I got that $A$ should have been $[0,1/2]$ as $2^{-n}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: That is also false.  $A$ is  not an interval at all. It is a countable set.

Comment: Oh yeah we're iterating over natural numbers... my mistake.

Comment: I suggest you write below your own answer to your question, now (for further reference). Picking a net as you did was a smart idea. Go on!

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you give me some hints on how to go further?

Comment: Let $f_x\to f\in A^{\mathbb R}$ and $u,v\in f^{1}(A\setminus\{0\})$ such that $f(u)=f(v).$ What can you say about this common value? And about $(f_x(u))$ and $(f_x(v))$? Btw may be I am missing sth, but why do you index your [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) by $\mathbb R$? Shouldn't it be indexed by an arbitrary [directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set)?

Comment: Can I assume that $f(c) = \frac{1}{2^c}$? If $u,v \in f^{-1}(A \setminus \{0\}) \iff f(u), f(v) \in A \setminus \{0\}$ and if $f(u) = f(v)$, then $f(u) = \frac{1}{2^u} =  \frac{1}{2^v} = f(v) \implies u = v$. And yes that is a flaw I think I should index it by some $\mathcal{A}$ an arbitary directed set. @AnneBauval

Comment: No, you cannot make extra assumptions about $f$. You can only say that the number $f(u)=f(v)$ is equal to $2^i$ for some $i$ (like in geetha290krm's answer).

Answer (score 1):

$A\setminus \{0\}=\{2^{-n}: n \geq 1\}$ is  an isolated set. Suppose $f \notin B$. Then there exist $x,y$ such that $x,\neq y$ and $f(x)=f(y) \neq 0$. Suppoe $f(x)=2^{-i}$. Let $r$ be the distance from $2^{-i}$ to $\{2^{-k}: k \neq i\}$.  If $|g(x)-f(x)| <r$ then $g(x)=f(x)$.  Similarly, $g(y)=f(y)$ if $|g(y)-f(y)| $ is small enough. It follows that $g(x)=f(x)=f(y)=g(y)$ whenever $|g(x)-f(x)| $ and $|g(y)-f(y)| $ are sufficently small This proves that the complement of $B$ is an open set, so $B$ is closed.

Comment: I don't think that this is a valid result. How do you suppose that $f(x) = 2^{-i}$ and do you mean that $r$ is a distance from a point to a set? Also how does $|g(x)-f(x)| <r \implies g(x) = f(x)$?

Comment: I agree with geetha290krm. Since $f\notin B,$ there exist $x,y$ distinct in $f^{-1}(A\setminus\{0\})$ such that $f(x)=f(y).$ Then, $f(x)\in A\setminus\{0\}=\{2^i;i\in\mathbb N\}.$ The distance from a point to a set is, by definition, the infimum of the distances of that point to any point of that set. And by definition of $r$, if $|g(x)-2^i|<r$ then $g(x)=2^i.$

Comment: In fact $r=2^{-(i+1)}.$

Comment: I don't understand why this shows that $B^c$ is open? By definition $B^c$ is open if for any $f \in B^c$ there exists a basic open set $U$ that is contained in $B$. Now $U = \prod_{x \in \Bbb R} V_x$, where $V_x$ are open in $A$ and $V_x = \Bbb R$ except for $x \in F \subset \Bbb R$ where $F$ is finite.  If now for any $g \in U$ we can show that $g$ restricted to $g^{-1}(A \setminus \{0\})$ is not injective we're done. @AnneBauval

Comment: Hum... $B^c$ is open iff any $f\in B^c$ belongs to some basic open set $U\subset B^c.$ This is exactly what geetha290krm shows, choosing $U=\prod_{t\in\mathbb R}V_t$ with $V_t=\{g\in A^{\mathbb R};|g(t)-f(t)|<r\} $ for $t=x$ or $y$ and $V_t=\mathbb R$ for all other $t$'s. @SleepWalker

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the set $V_t$'s should be open in $A$ not in $A^\Bbb R$? It would now seem that $V_t=\{g\in A^{\mathbb R};|g(t)-f(t)|<r\}$ is a subset of $A^\Bbb R$ and not $A$. @AnneBauval

Comment: Woops sorry (for $t=x$ or $y$) $V_t=(f(t)-r,f(t)+r)$ @SleepWalker.

Comment: Now this starts to make sense. It seems that the solution geetha290krm proposed doesn't need to use the fact that we're excluding zero from $A$ that is $A \setminus \{0\}$? @AnneBauval

Comment: Also this $V_t=(f(t)-r,f(t)+r)$ is likely still not valid as the open sets in $A$ are all isolated and of the form $O \cap A$ for $O$ open in $\Bbb R$. This $V_t$ is now an open interval. @AnneBauval

Comment: It uses the exclusion of $0$ which, contrarily to the other points of $A$, is not isolated. And yes, replace our $V_t$'s by $V_t\cap A$ (including your "$V_x=\mathbb R$ except..."). @SleepWalker

Comment: Thanks for the reply and your time! I think I still try and see if I can approach the problem with a different approach this way with defining $r$ was not the most natural one for me. @AnneBauval